# Laravel error when using dynamic class names returned by method

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

In Laravel (4 & 5), I am trying to use dynamic class names and then call them directly, but receiving a fatal error if not first storing them in a local string variable.

Assuming I have a basic class:

```
class SimpleModel {
     private $modelName;

     function __construct($id) {

        $this->modelName = AnotherModel::getName($id);

    }
}
```

Within the methods, I can easily do

```
$modelName = $this->modelName;
$modelName::find(1);
```

But I get a fatal error when trying the following:

```
$this->modelName::find(1);
```

This triggers a `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException` with a message of

```
syntax error, unexpected &#039;::&#039; (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)
```

Basically the `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` is a syntax error generated from the `::` symbol.

Can't wrap my head around why Laravel (or PHP in general) allows dynamic class names when using a local variable (within a method) but not a class variable.

I also tried putting it in a seprate method `getModelName()` method but getting the same error.

```
$this->getModelName()::find(1);
```

Instanciating a new class every time (`new $this->modelName`) is not a good solution.

I was looking into using PHP's `Reflection` but not sure how to do it without instanciating a new class every time.
Since it is working when using a local string, it seems as `Reflection` might be an over kill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to how the PHP parser works (up to PHP 5). The `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` token (`::`) is only allowed after `T_STRING` (that represents a class name, not a string within quotes) or, since PHP 5.3, `T_VARIABLE`.

But **your code will work in PHP 7**, where the parser has been fundamentally reworked (see: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/abstract_syntax_tree)

Demo: https://3v4l.org/sdBss

Comment: Thanks for explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *call_user_func* or *call_user_func_array* to call method of a class, the name of which is stored in object's attribute:

```
call_user_func(array($this->modelName, 'find'), 1)
```

OR

```
call_user_func_array(array($this->modelName, 'find'), array(1))
```

Comment: That works, but still doesn't explain why this is happening. Any idea?

Comment: Because it’s simply not supported.

Comment: Since PHP 5.3 it is allowed to call static methods and access static attributes using dynamic class names stored in variables, e.g.: $a::foo(), but it stiill doesn't allow what you're trying to do. It's also not clear to me what benefit you see in calling static methods such unusual way.